# Why are there no .pkg downloads available for R 4.3 versions?

Tags: r, installation, version

You can easily download and install R versions 4.0.0 through 4.2.3 via this link:
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/base/

However, I cannot find any downloadable .pkg files for R version 4.3.0 for mac, only the .tar.gz files which need to be configured after downloading.
Is there a reason for this that I am too inexperienced to grasp, or have I somehow missed what I'm looking for after hours of googling?

I made the mistake of updating to R 4.3.2 in the middle of an ongoing study and now a SCTK function that used to take 10 seconds takes 15 minutes. I have ragrets and want to return to the previous version I was using (4.3.0).

I tried installing previous package versions on 4.3.2 and this breaks one of the SCTK functions I need. I tried installing 4.2.3 but this version of R is incompatible with the package versions I am trying to install, and makes installation of even basic packages like tidyverse a nightmare. I tried configuring R 4.3.0 from the .tar file but there is a lot of conflicting/unclear information on the best approach, and I am running into repeated errors. Ideally, I would like to find R-4.3.0.pkg somewhere and download it, and install it.

Comment: You might want to file an issue on their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/usnistgov/SCTK/issues) to get some help. Don't forget to include a self-contained example to increase chance of fast reply.